# How to save date of user login into another table using php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Noobie here.... Apologies if the question looks silly

I have database table Users which stores the details of the user from the registration form.

the table contains:

```
Users(id, username,password)
```

I have created another table to store the date of logins of the user.

```
user_login(id, user_id, login_date)
```

here the user_id is the foreign key for the id from users.

```
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);

 if (empty($username)) {
 array_push($errors, "Username is required");
 }
 if (empty($password)) {
 array_push($errors, "Password is required");
 }

 if (count($errors) == 0) {
 $password = md5($password);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $name=$_SESSION['username'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $indate= mysqli_query("INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, login_date) SELECT u.id FROM user as u WHERE username='$name'AND login_date= '$date'");
  mysqli_query($db, $indate);

 // $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  header('location: profile.php');
  }else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
  }
  }
  }
```

The above code is to the check the login of the users. I wanted to add the date to the table user_login while the user logs in.

Can someone help me to implement the query. I have searched in google and here in stackoverflow, but i couldn't find any posts related to mine. Kindly help me with this problem

Comment: You can check the record for the day before the insertion of the new record.

Comment: Put a unique index on the combination of user_id and login_date, then any attempt to insert an additional record for an already existing combination of the two will fail.

Comment: Why would you want to add another row if they log in on the same or other day?

Comment: @AlokMali Can you show me how its done, I am new with php and mysql

Comment: @esqew i have edited the post. can you check now

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this logic to achieve your functionality**

```
<?php 
  $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
  //modify this query based on your framework
  $userTodayResult = "select * from user_login where user_id = ".$userId." and login_date = "$todayDate"";


if(empty($userTodayResult)){
  //insert your record with today date 
}
?>
```